# „Lag“ oder „gelegen habe“?

Tags: colloquial

Was ist gebräuchlicher in der Alltagssprache?

1.1. Ich habe falsch gelegen!

1.2. Ich lag falsch!

2.1. Meine Taschenuhr lag auf dem Tisch.

2.2. Meine Taschenuhr hat auf dem Tisch gelegen.

Comment: Ohne Kontext schwer zu beantworten. Google-Suche findet wesentlich mehr Treffer für die Präteritum-Varianten.

Comment: Ich frage nach der Alltagsverwendung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In Österreich:

1.3. Ich **bin** falsch gelegen!
2.3. Meine Taschenuhr **ist** auf dem Tisch gelegen.

Das hat zwei Gründe:

**1. Warum *»bin/ist«*? Warum nicht *»habe/hat«*?**

Im österreichischen Deutsch verlangen die Verben, die die Art des Aufenthalts an einem bestimmten Ort beschreiben (stehen, liegen, sitzen) nicht das Hilfsverb *»haben«* sondern das Hilfsverb *»sein«.* (Siehe auch [Wikipedia: Österreichisches Deutsch - Positionsverben](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch#Perfekt:_haben_und_sein_bei_Positionsverben))

> Ich **bin** im Bett gelegen.
> Ich werde im Bett gelegen **sein.**

Das gilt nicht nur, wenn diese Verben im ursprünglichen Sinn verwendet werden, sondern auch, wenn sie im übertragenen Sinn verwendet werden. Das ist österreichisches Standarddeutsch und findet sich in österreichischen Schulbüchern und in österreichischen Gesetzen wieder, aber das entspricht auch der in Österreich verwendeten Alltagssprache.

Soweit mir bekannt ist, wird auch in Teilen Bayerns und Baden Württembergs das Hilfsverb *»sein«* in der Alltagssprache verwendet, ist dort aber nicht Teil der an Schulen gelehrten Standardsprache, sondern wird als dialektal angesehen. Auch in der Schweiz ist das so. Mir ist aber nicht bekannt, ob in der Schweiz das Hilfsverb *»sein«* bei den genannten Verben nur im Dialekt oder auch im Schweizerischen Standarddeutsch (also in Schulbüchern und Gesetzen) verwendet wird.

**2. Warum Perfekt? Warum nicht Präteritum?**

Daran ist der [oberdeutsche Präteritumschwund](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberdeutscher_Pr%C3%A4teritumschwund) schuld.

Man nennt die Dialekte, die südlich der [Speyerer Linie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speyerer_Linie_(Isoglosse)) gesprochen werden, *»oberdeutsche Dialekte«* (weil sie oben, auf den Bergen gesprochen werden). Dort liegen die Schweiz, Liechtenstein, Österreich, Südtirol, Bayern und Baden Württemberg. Auch Teile einiger angrenzender Bundesländer Deutschlands gehören zum oberdeutschen Sprachraum.

In diesem Gebiet ist das Präteritum (fast) vollständig aus den Dialekten verschwunden und wurde durch das Perfekt ersetzt. In Deutschland betrifft dieses Phänomen nur einen Teil des Staatsgebiets (nämlich den Süden). Daher gilt in Deutschland das Ersetzen des Präteritums durch das Perfekt als Eigenschaft eines Dialekts, der in die Alltagssprache hineinwirkt. Die pauschale Verwendung des Perfekt für alles, was in der Vergangenheit geschah, ist im deutschen Standarddeutsch nicht korrekt.

Österreich liegt aber vollständig im oberdeutschen Sprachgebiet. Daher ist die Verwendung des Perfekt in Situationen, in denen man in Norddeutschland das Präteritum verwenden würde, ein Teil der österreichischen Standardsprache (Schulunterricht, Gesetze, usw.). Der oben bereits verlinkte Wikipedia-Artikel über österreichisches Deutsch enthält auch zu diesem Thema [ein Kapitel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96sterreichisches_Deutsch#Pr%C3%A4teritum/Imperfekt). Aus diesem Grund nennt man in österreichischen Schulbüchern das Perfekt auch ganz einfach nur *»Vergangenheit«.* (Das Präteritum heißt in der Grammatik des österreichischen Standarddeutsch *»Mitvergangenheit«.*)

---

#### In Deutschland, südlich der Speyerer Linie

1.2. Ich habe falsch gelegen!
2.2. Meine Taschenuhr hat auf dem Tisch gelegen.

Begründung: Oberdeutsche Präteritumschwund (siehe oben)

Je nachdem, wie stark sich ein Sprecher im Dialekt oder in der Standardsprache zuhause fühlt, wird man südlich der Speyerer Linie gelegentlich auch eine Form des Hilfsverbs *»sein«* verwenden.

---

#### In Deutschland, nördlich der Speyerer Linie

Hier hängt es vom Kontext ab. Wenn der Irrtum Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat, wird man das Perfekt verwenden:

> Ich habe falsch gelegen und die Wette verloren. Deswegen muss ich nun in dieser kleinen Wohnung wohnen.

Wenn der Irrtum keine Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat, wird das Präteritum bevorzugt:

> Na und? Ich hatte eine Einzelmeinung und lag damit falsch. Aber es wurde dann ohnehin gemacht, was die Mehrheit für richtig hielt, also ist es egal.

Ähnlich ist es beim zweiten Beispiel. Wenn der Dieb die Uhr gestohlen hat, und sie nun weg ist, dann hat die Uhr auf dem Tisch gelegen als der Dieb vorbeikam. Wenn ich sie aber nur kurz vergessen hatte, zurückging und sie dann an mich nahm, ohne dass das irgendwelche Konsequenzen hatte, dann lag sie auf dem Tisch.

Comment: Ich kann dir versichern, dass wir hier im Norden *Ich lag falsch und hab die Wette verloren* sagen. Das hat nichts mit Grammatik zu tun, sondern damit, dass das Verb *liegen* eins der Verben ist, bei denen  Präteritum als Abkürzung für Perfekt verwendet wird.

Comment: @Janka: »Präteritum als Abkürzung für Perfekt« - davon habe ich noch nie gehört. Warum schreibst du keine Antwort auf die gestellte Frage? Dort könntest du diese Behauptung genauer ausführen, denn die Frage dreht sich ja genau darum.

Comment: Weil der Rest deiner ursprünglichen Antwort ja stimmte. Deine jetzige Antwort verdreht es aber wieder. Dieser oberdeutsche Präteritumschwund ist zwar eine Tatsache. Nun ist das Perfekt für die Vergangenheit aber schon seit mindestens hundert  Jahren Teil der Standardsprache geworden. Auch im Norden machen wir uns keine Gedanken mehr darüber, ob eine Handlung Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat oder nicht. …

Comment: …  Wir verwenden normalerweise immer Perfekt, genau wie ihr im Süden. Die einzige Ausnahme sind die Hilfsverben und die Modalverben, da verwenden wir praktisch immer Präteritum, und so ein paar Verben wie *geben*, *liegen*, *fahren*, wo wir in bestimmten Zusammenhängen, z.B. *daran lag es* das Präteritum bevorzugen. Die Bedeutung ist aber genau dieselbe wie *daran hat es gelegen*. Die beiden Varianten sind völlig austauschbar. Du kannst auch an diesem Beispiel gut sehen, dass es keine Rolle spielt, ob die Handlung Auswirkungen auf die Gegenwart hat oder nicht.